# Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 8 - Projects building when not checked in Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-8, deployment-project

I am maintaining a legacy application in Visual Studio 2008 and my office is deploying Windows 8.  These factors are out of my control.

My Visual Studio solution contains a Deployment project.  When I set my build configuration to "Debug", I can see that the Deployment project is not checked.  Yet, when I build the solution, I get an error from the Deployment project about a file that it cannot find (the file exists, but that is another story).

Under Windows 7, this behaves as it should.  Is this a known issue, or is there something else I can do to get Visual Studio to respect the settings in Configuration Manager?

Comment: I'm having a problem with a deployment project in VS2008 under Win 8 (actually Server 2012) also, but in my case I'm _trying_ to build the deployment but it won't build, complaining about not being able to create a temp file that it actually does create.  Works fine on an XP system.  I wonder if there is any connection...